# Mongo - How to check an existing field before insert or update a given document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Im using Mongodb in NodeJs and I would like to know if it exists a right way to check an existing field before insert and update a given document.

Let's assume i have a collection named 'gates'  that i want to insert new document or to update an existing document into. So, i tried this

```
let exist = db.collection('gates').find({_id: {$eq: somevalue}}).toArray(
    (err, res) => {
        if(err) throw err;

        return res.length > 0;  
    }
);
```

Here is my problem, my variable *exist* has an undefined value and not a boolean value. How can i fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a Promise because the query is evaluated async.

```
static countGates(somevalue) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.collection('gates').find({_id: {$eq: somevalue}}).toArray(
            (err, res) => {
                if(err) {
                    reject(err);
                }
                resolve(res.length > 0);  
            }
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: @LChampo, being this an async operation there will always be a Promise, callback or code inside de request. Take a look at the 'await' operator, might help a little bit.

Comment: In fact, i noticed that nothing is added into database. Is it normal ?

Comment: @LChampo, we are talking about the "find" operation in this post and I think I provided a valid solution to your problem. Now, if you are having issues inserting/updating data then open another question in stackoverflow.

Comment: I tested again today and now i no longer insertion and update problem. 

And Yes, your solution stay valid